# Is there a way to create a NeutralinoJS project based on Svelte and Typescript?

Tags: typescript, svelte, neutralinojs

I need to create a neutralino+svelte+ts project, I've noted it was possible in old version ([neutralino-cli@1.8.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@neutralinojs/neu/v/1.8.1)) but nothing similar is described in newest version of [neutralino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@neutralinojs/neu). I've tried to run in latest neutralino version the same command described in version `1.8.1` (`neu create myapp --template svelte`) but I received the error:

`neu: ERROR Unable to download resources from internet. Please check your internet connection and template URLs.`

I've tried with different type of template (`ts` and `js`) and I had the same result.

I've tried also by running the command `neu create myapp --template neutralinojs/neutralinojs-svelte` (same error).

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it without any dedicated template, it's quite simple and easy.

Basically, you need to create a Neutralino app and a Svelte app side by side in the same root folder, then a little config to make them work together.

Detailed step by step :

1. Create a Neutralino app, following Neutralino documentation : https://neutralino.js.org/docs/getting-started/your-first-neutralinojs-app. Ensure you can run and build as in the tutorial.
2. In the root folder of your Neutralino application, rename `.gitignore` to `.gitignore-neu` and `readme.md` to `readme-neu.md`
3. In the Svelte REPL, download the zip file you want to start from, for example https://svelte.dev/repl/hello-world (click the download button on right side of the toolbar)
4. Copy the content of the zip file in your Neutralino root folder, so that Svelte `public` folder is at the same level as Neutralino `resources` folder
5. Run `npm install` to setup the Svelte application. Ensure it works ok on its own by running `npm run dev` and `npm run build`

Now you have two standalone applications side by side in the same root folder. Let’s make them work together.

6. Merge Neutralino and Svelte .gitignore files by copying `.gitignore-neu` content into `.gitignore`
7. Open the file `/neutralino.config.json` and change `"documentRoot":"/resources/"` to `"documentRoot":"/public/"` so that Neutralino can use the Svelte output
8. Open two console windows : `npm run dev` for Svelte and `neu run` for Neutralino. You'll see a Neutralino native window displaying the Svelte home page.

You’re done !

Now you can code your Svelte web application in the `/src` folder as you would for any Svelte application, with hot-compiling by Svelte and hot-reloading by Neutralino.

When your app is ready, build it with `npm run build` (Svelte part) followed by `neu build` (Neutralino).

If you need to use Neutralino API from within your Svelte code :

- Copy the file `/resources/js/neutralino.js` to the `/public/` folder
- add the line `<script src="/neutralino.js"></script>` to the `<head>` block of `/public/index.html` (right after the line `<script defer src='/build/bundle.js'></script>`)
- Add `Neutralino.init();` in Svelte main.js file (`/src/main.js`)

If you need Typescript, install a Neutralino Typescript app at step 1, and run Svelte Typescript setup script after the step 5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and welcome to stackoverflow, do you know if there is a way to use typescript in the project?

Comment: I have the same need as @Raffaele: Neu + Svelte + TS. I need the Neu API. I added `<script src="/neutralino.js"></script>` to the `<head>` block of `/public/index.html`, however, adding `Neutralino.init()` to `main.ts` fails, as TS cannot find `Neutralino`. Should I import it from somewhere? … You also mention to install _Neutralino Typescrip app at step 1_, but don’t mention from where. Could you add this info please? Thanks!

Comment: I solved it by installing `neutralinojs-types` NPM package and adding `import 'neutralinojs-types'` before `app` variable definition and `Neutralino.init()` after it and before `export default app`, all in `main.ts`.